# date-fns.distanceInWordsStrict failing when used in react-native

Tags: react-native, date-fns

Not able to find time difference between two Calendar dates using date-fns.distanceInWordsStrict.

I am trying to use distanceInWordsStrict to calculate exact time difference between two Calendar Dates. Using distanceInWordsStrict is a mandatory requirement. When i use other functions of date-fns like format , differenceInCalendarWeeks, differenceInCalendarWeeks, i get the desired output. But when distanceInWordsStrict is used, the app crashes with attached error message.

date-fns and react-native versions are following as per my package.json file.
    "date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",

```
 import {distanceInWordsStrict} from 'date-fns'
 console.log(distanceInWordsStrict(
 new Date(2014, 6, 2),
 new Date(2015, 0, 2)
 )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function was renamed from distanceInWordsStrict to formatDistanceStrict to make its name consistent with format and formatRelative
So try *import {formatDistanceStrict} from 'date-fns'*